# XULrunner not running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xul, xulrunner

I'm using Linux Mint, and I've downloaded XUL 1.8.0.4. Extracted it to the `/opt/` dir, made symbolic link to /usr/bin/xulrunner, and I still can't run XUL apps.

When I type `xulrunner -version` in terminal, I got message:

`Mozilla XULRunner 1.8.0.4`

When I type `whereis xulrunner` i got message

`xulrunner: /usr/bin/xulrunner /usr/lib/xulrunner /usr/bin/X11/xulrunner`

So it should work, but when I go in the app folder and run `xulrunner application.ini` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application have any files other than `application.ini` ? I think you need at least a preferences file (`defaults/preferences/prefs.js`) and a `chrome.manifest` (or an omni.ja with these in it) to make xulrunner actually do anything. If you just feed it a lone `application.ini` it parses the ini, goes looking for more application files, then exits when it finds none.